# How can i set offset of messageViewController in MessageKit?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, chat, messagekit

my messageViewController of **Messagekit** is showing messages like this , how can i set offset of messages to show below the navigation bar ?

[image]

**my code for messageViewController Layout**

```
 func configureView(){

    scrollsToBottomOnKeyboardBeginsEditing = true // default false
    maintainPositionOnKeyboardFrameChanged = true // default false

let layout = messagesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? MessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout
layout?.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 8, bottom: 1, right: 8)

// Hide the outgoing avatar and adjust the label alignment to line up with the messages
layout?.setMessageOutgoingAvatarSize(.zero)
layout?.setMessageOutgoingMessageTopLabelAlignment(LabelAlignment(textAlignment: .right, textInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 8)))
layout?.setMessageOutgoingMessageBottomLabelAlignment(LabelAlignment(textAlignment: .right, textInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 8)))

// Set outgoing avatar to overlap with the message bubble
layout?.setMessageIncomingMessageTopLabelAlignment(LabelAlignment(textAlignment: .left, textInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 18, bottom: outgoingAvatarOverlap, right: 0)))
layout?.setMessageIncomingAvatarSize(CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
layout?.setMessageIncomingMessagePadding(UIEdgeInsets(top: -outgoingAvatarOverlap, left: -18, bottom: outgoingAvatarOverlap, right: 18))

layout?.setMessageIncomingAccessoryViewSize(CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
layout?.setMessageIncomingAccessoryViewPadding(HorizontalEdgeInsets(left: 8, right: 0))
layout?.setMessageIncomingAccessoryViewPosition(.messageBottom)
layout?.setMessageOutgoingAccessoryViewSize(CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
layout?.setMessageOutgoingAccessoryViewPadding(HorizontalEdgeInsets(left: 0, right: 8))

messagesCollectionView.messagesLayoutDelegate = self
messagesCollectionView.messagesDisplayDelegate = self
}
```

**If I hide the navigation bar it shows like this**

[image]

Comment: try to set `contentInset` for `messagesCollectionView` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` `self.messagesCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 70, left: 0, bottom: 70, right: 0)`

Answer (score 3):

Are you using **IQKeyboardManager**?

If so then you can fix the issue simply by adding this in `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

`IQKeyboardManager.shared.disabledDistanceHandlingClasses.append(YourChatVC.self)`

Comment: It seems like this could be the solution :) .... Thanks alot for this .. will surely gonna try this whenever I implement this again (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Add content inset padding to messagesCollectionView

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   self.messagesCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 70, left: 0, bottom: 70, right: 0)
}
```

Comment: i have done it , its not working .... afer doing this initially message is behind navigation bar but when i scrolls then it set 70pt from navigation bar ...

Comment: then you can use container view and extend it as messageviewcontroller

Comment: can you please guide me how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change messagesCollectionView contentSize in viewDidLayoutSubviews